# Allow Profiles To ONLY See Records Created By Their Profile

Tags: lightning-apps, permissions, profile, sharing, user

I have been put to the task of cleaning up our companies Salesforce org. We have lots of apps on it, and each profile has it's own org. So the main issue I am running into is other profiles seeing records that were created by other profiles in a different app.

I have looked into the org-wide defaults as well as the sharing rules and permission sets and everything looks as it should, there is no `view all` selected on any profile, but yet, everyone can see everyone's records.

Where should I start looking into so i can get this cleaned up and organized?

Comment: This is a very broad question and will probably need more details about users and setup of objects and type of edition you have. Record sharing is controlled by OWD, Roles, sharing rules and apex sharing. If you have checked all these places then see if they have modify or view all data permission. You can check this easily by narrowing down a user who is able to see all data, then the object for which all data is visible.. Goto sharing setting and from the dropdown, select that object and read all options present on that page especially profiles section. Then go through the permission sets

Comment: assigned to that user and see in system permissions.  If possible add details about object and org setup

Comment: I checked all of that, everything looks good, no perm sets have any view all on them. After doing some research, would my request even be possible? To make only one profile see records created by the profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As manjit5190 pointed out in the comments, profiles don't control what records people see; they control what *kinds* of records they can see.

For example, say a business has two profiles that can see opportunities -- Sales and Support. Sales needs access to opportunities so that they can generate new revenue, and support needs access to submit replacement sales when devices break in the field. Both profiles need access to create/read/update opportunities, so access is granted to both because profiles control the *kind of thing* to which users have access.

Sales and Support will have access to all and edit all opportunities if org-wide details are configured to Public Read / Write. This doesn't sound like your desire, so you'd need to change that to Private, allowing users to see only the opportunities they own (typically the ones they've created).

If you then want all of support to have access to all support opportunities, you'd need to open the sharing settings up through some *record-level sharing* mechanism, such as roles or sharing rules. The key thing thing to remember is that profiles and permission sets control the types of records users can access, whereas roles, sharing rules, OWDs and other things control the records themselves.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_data_access.htm&type=5

Comment: I did something that sort of achieved what I was trying to do. I basically added a role for the profiles I was needing to have their owner separate view and I assigned a list view to the Role and filtered it by Account Owner Alias.